# How can I generate binary classification dataset and control the overlapping between 2 classes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

Is it possible to control overlapping while generating dataset with sklearn.datasets.make_classification?

I want to pass overlapping percentages between 2 classes and it will overlap the classes according to the given percentage.

**The detailed requirement is:**
*Generate an n-class classification dataset(Gaussian manner) in such a way that we can control it by adding covariance, overlapping percentage, and the shape of plot like a diagonal, straight line, horizontal line, etc*
[image: Shape of plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_classification` draws samples from an n-dimensional hypercube. You might be able to achieve something like "overlapping classes according to a given percentage" by tweaking the `class_sep` parameter in specific cases, but I don't think it would work generally.

A solution might be to create binary classification data sets by sampling from Gaussian distributions with known mean and variance. Here's a short demo:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = default_rng()

N_POINTS = 10000
SCALE = 1.3

train_data = np.c_[
    np.r_[rng.normal(5, SCALE, (N_POINTS, 2)), rng.normal(10, SCALE, (N_POINTS, 2))],
    np.r_[np.zeros((N_POINTS, 1)), np.ones((N_POINTS, 1))],
]

# Plotting
fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(train_data[:, 0], train_data[:, 1], c=train_data[:, 2])
ax.set_box_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

Here's an example where `SCALE = 0.5`:

[image: two gaussian blobs with scale 0.5, they are nowhere close to overlapping]

... and here's an example where `SCALE = 1.3`:

[image: two gaussian blobs with scale 1.3, they appear to overlap slightly]

Samples generated by [`rng.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.normal.html) should generally fall within two standard deviations from the means we located at `(5, 5)` and `(10, 10)`.

Changing the `SCALE` parameter, knowing that the distance between your means is around 7.071, and knowing the expected radius of where your data should fall---should let you estimate how much overlap you expect to have between your classes.

Once you've done that, you can translate your findings back into parameters of [`sklearn.datasets.make_blobs`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html)

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. That's exactly what I wanted